# Trying to make a css layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to do the below layout but I want this layout to be supported from old browsers too, at least IE8 (ie7 and ie6 support would be also good).

The part with number 2, with height 100% I mean height 100% - 50px above, sames apply and to the other similar cases. Basically I want to have the below layout so it would not have x and y scroll.

I tried different things and came up to this *ugly* result:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/anjlK/)

Note: I don't mind the use of javascript but prefer to use css where possible.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test it in all browsers, but seems to work in chrome. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeBso/
Basically what I did was used position `absolute` on some divs in order to make their height 100%, and used `float: left` on divs that are inside of `chat` div.

Comment: Thank you very much its working on IE8+ .. I don't care much about ie6-7 for now :)